# What is the correct way to encode a json and send it to the backend in Objective C?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I have the following codebase:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ip_address"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
NSString *imageDataEncoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [jsonRequest setObject:imageDataEncoded forKey:@"data"];
NSError *error;
NSData *dataFromDict = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonRequest options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

[request setHTTPBody:dataFromDict];
```

Is this the right way?

At the backend where I have Python using requests library to receive the request and parse the json, I have a line of code as follows:

```
print(base64.b64decode(request.form.get('data'))
```

This prints the first few characters of the request as follows:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('{"data":"\\/9j\\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASA`
```

As you can see it is really not a json because it has got several ' marks.

How can I best handle the JSON received and what is the best way to send the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this it is the case with backend on python. I've converted NSDictionary to NSData as you've done and with other methods, and get similar request body on NodeJS.
It seems NSDictionary is not converted to NSData properly, because key-value of dictionary is sent as key on request

Post body data from NSDictionary:
[image: NSDictionary to NSData]

However, converting from NSString to NSData gives more reliable JSON data:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
NSString *imageDataEncoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@", imageDataEncoded];
NSData *bodyData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

**UPDATED**

After some investigations I've found out, I should have set Content-Type in the headers of the request.

```
 [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

And then sending NSData converted from NSDictionary worked as expected.

(Note: I was using ExpressJS as backend with body-parser in middleware )